# "We rarely go on holiday." Can I say "Us neither"?

Tags: personal-pronouns, subject-or-object

Since, in the first person singular, I can compare my situation, tastes, etc. to someone else's saying "Neither do I." or "Me neither."…

… is it possible to use all the other personal pronouns in the same way?

"Us neither." "Him/Her neither." "Them neither." etc.

Comment: They all sound OK to me.

Comment: They all sound horrible to me, but so does "me neither" so that's really just my preference.

Comment: What I commonly hear in this instance is "We don't, either."

Comment: If you really want to shake things up, try "So don't we."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned above, it's all down to usage and "us neither" is not commonly used, with people preferring the phrase "neither do we" - for that reason I would stick with saying "neither do we".

I would say the same is true of the other personal pronouns: "neither do they", etc.

Comment: I would say ***we/he/they neither***. It seems to me that ***we*** is the subject of one's 'sentence' (albeit that most of it is elided, including the verb). I accept that it is complicated by the fact that if one said the whole sentence one would use 'either'. *We seldom go on holiday either*.

Comment: @WS2 Would you say "I neither"? I'm not convinced that you're suggested sentence is actually what's going on here.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus See discussion below. Clearly with the first person singular the object pronoun would appear to be idiomatic.

Comment: That's not something I've heard people use generally, @WinnieNiclaus, but perhaps it's in use where you live?

it's "your suggested sentence" btw not "you're suggested sentence" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with saying "us neither", but (and you mention it in your second line) I'd tend to go for "neither do we".

"neither do we" - 473k hits on Google

"us neither" - 374k

Comment: "nor we" - 470k hits on Google
"nor us" - 133k hits on Google

Comment: The problem with Google search is that it tailors the results to your history. Try [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=us+neither%2Cneither+do+we&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cus%20neither%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cneither%20do%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bneither%20do%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNeither%20do%20we%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree that using **neither** or **either** in this scenario is correct: you use those in the case of a negative statement, but the statement in question is positive.  If the statement was the negative version:

> We don't go on vacation often.

Then the response would be "We don't either" or "Neither do we" or (colloquially) "Us neither".

But when the statement is positive:

> We rarely go on vacation.

Then the response should be `So do we` or `We do, too` or (colloquially) `Us too`.

Granted, few will bat an eye, and everyone will know what you mean, if you respond conversationally to "We rarely go on vacation" with "Neither do we".  It is easy to flip the original statement into the negative grammatical form "We don't go on vacation much".

But still, technically the reply is nonsensical, because it is effectively "Neither do we (rarely go on vacation)".  The original statement is affirmative, and it doesn't make grammatical sense to append a "neither" to an affirmation.

Comment: That's because 'rarely', like 'hardly ever', for instance, has a negative meaning!

Comment: @user58319 right - maybe I'm being too literal or technical about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say ***we/he/they neither***. It seems to me that ***we*** is the subject of the 'sentence' (albeit that most of it is elided, including the verb). It therefore requires a subject pronoun.

I accept that it is complicated by the fact that if one said the whole sentence one would use 'either'. *We seldom go on holiday either*.

Comment: It's also complicated by the fact that in the analogous first-person situation, the overwhelmingly common usage is _me neither_ rather than _I neither_.

Comment: @aps I thought of that. It is interesting that idiomatically we use the object pronoun in the first person singular, but the subject pronoun elsewhere. One of the quirks of spoken English.

Comment: @aps since "me neither" elides the rest of the sentence, you can fill it out however you like.  For example, it could be shorthand for "(Your statement is not true for) me either".  I know that's a bit of a reach, but it's how I rationalize it.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the responses that go with "neither," but intuition and my ear tell me that "nor do we" is the better choice. I wanted to give a grammatical backing for this, but I have to admit that "neither is he" seems to sound just as good as if not better than "nor is he," which can sound a bit stilted. However in cases when we're not using a copula but rather an auxiliary verb like "do," "can," or "has," "nor" sounds better.

Comment: I grew up in the NE US; children would say "me neither," but adults were expected to say "Nor/neither do I" or "Nor/neither do we."